# Subscribe one and two topics have differences

Tags: c#, mqtt

Subscribe to topic through mqtt, but when I only subscribe to one, the return is always empty. But when I subscribe to both topics at the same time, everything becomes normal again.

```
// Subscribe
            client.UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler(e =>
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("subscribe successfully");               
                Console.WriteLine("### RECEIVED APPLICATION MESSAGE ###");
                Console.WriteLine($"+ Topic = {e.ApplicationMessage.Topic}");
                Console.WriteLine($"+ Payload = {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload)}");
                Console.WriteLine($"+ QoS = {e.ApplicationMessage.QualityOfServiceLevel}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            });
            await client.SubscribeAsync(new MqttTopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic("XXX").Build());
            await client.SubscribeAsync(new MqttTopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic("XXX").Build());

            client.UseDisconnectedHandler(e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("disconnected");
            });

            
            await client.DisconnectAsync();
```

Comment: It looks like you are connecting, subscribing and then immediately disconnecting? I suspect that the second `SubscribeAsync` is really just acting as a delay providing time for messages to be received (try replacing, for testing only, the second `SubscribeAsync` with a `Thread.Sleep`). Consider rearchitecting things so the connection stays open.

Comment: thanks for your help. I add `Console.ReadLine()` to prevent disconnection. While this is not a good approach, it also avoids errors. Hope to find a better way in the future.